# I put the 'ball' variable on global and i keep getting error messages when i call it again

Tags: python

```
import pygame
 width = 800 
 height = 600 
 player1_pos_y = 250
 player2_pos_y = 250
 vel_bol_x = 9
 vel_bol_y = 9

 def load():
   global clock
   clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

     

def update(dt):
  global player1_pos_y, player2_pos_y
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

   

            
def draw_screen(screen):
  global ball
  screen.fill((0,0,0))
  player1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (0, 250, 10, 100))
  player2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (790, 250, 10, 100))    
  ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), (400,250), 10 )
  linha = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (400, 0, 2, 600))

def main_loop(screen):  
  global ball, clock
  ball.x += vel_bol_x
  ball.y += vel_bol_y
  running = True
  while running:
      for e in pygame.event.get(): 
          if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False
              break

      clock.tick(60)         
      dt = clock.get_time()
      draw_screen(screen)
      update(dt)
    pygame.display.update() 
 pygame.init()
 pygame.mixer.init()
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
 pygame.display.set_caption("Exemplo de Audio")
 load()
 main_loop(screen)
 pygame.quit()
```

I wanted to call the variable 'ball' again but it keep getting error, im currently making a pong game in pygame, I need to keep the variable ball in this function becausw is an assignment, im kinda new to the library so bare with me.

> ```
> Exception has occurred: NameError
> name 'ball' is not defined
>  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Pong T9.py", line 32, in main_loop
>    ball.x += vel_bol_x
>    ^^^^
>  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\Pong T9.py", line 56, in <module>
>    main_loop(screen)
> NameError: name 'ball' is not defined
> ```

The error in question

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code, but the likely problem is that you are calling `main_loop` before you call `draw_screen`, so the variable doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Also, please include the error traceback that you are encountering.

Comment: I just eddited all the code in, its not complete yet but the error is there too.

Comment: As Tim has said, you are calling `main_loop` before calling `draw_screen`. More specifically, it does not seem like you are calling `draw_screen` at all. `ball` is only initialised in `draw_screen`, so that needs to happen before you call `main_loop`.

Comment: i called, the main loop is after draw screen, but the thing is that draw screen is inside the for that is inside main loop, so im calling draw screen only when main loop is called.

    def main_loop(screen):  
      global ball, clock
      ball.x += vel_bol_x
      ball.y += vel_bol_y
      running = True
      while running:
          for e in pygame.event.get(): 
              if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  running = False
                  break

          clock.tick(60)         
          dt = clock.get_time()
          draw_screen(screen)

Answer (score 1):

There are two substantive issues with your code.

The first, as several commenters pointed out, is that you are trying to modify attributes on `ball` before it has been initialized for the first time. That's because `ball` is only created when `draw_screen` runs, but you only call that towards the end of `main_loop`, whereas you modify `ball.x` and `ball.y` at the top of that function. Fixing this issue would not be hard, but I'm not going to do so, because there's a deeper issue.

The second issue with the code is that `ball` isn't currently a useful object for you to be manipulating. It's not an object that represents a ball drawn on the screen, which will move on the screen when you modify its coordinates. It's a `Rect` object that got returned by `pygame.draw.circle`. That rectangle is just informative, it shows you which parts of the screen were drawn on (which is only really useful if you're doing something fancy and not redrawing the whole screen every frame). Editing `ball`'s attributes will do nothing useful, since no other code is going to read from it to determine where to draw (you could write such code yourself, maybe, but you'd probably want to create your own `Rect` or some other object, instead of using the return value from `pygame.draw.circle()` to create it). Each time you call `draw_screen`, you're drawing all the objects at exactly the same position, hard-coded. If you want your objects to be moving around, you need to use variables for those draw calls! And unless you're attempting some tricky 2D pixel masking stuff, you generally don't need to use the return value from the draw calls at all.

If you're willing to use a slightly more complicated Object Oriented style of coding, you might want to create a subclass of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. The base class makes it easy to do a lot of the things you were trying to make your current code do (e.g. drawing an image based on saved coordinates that can be updated).